# How to rotate UIButton like in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, rotation

How can I make rotation, like in iPhone(when holding finger on the icon to delete item). I need apply this to UIButton. Help please how to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

To rotate a button use the transform property of UIView to add rotation

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```